# jQuery Smooth Scroll to ID on same and on other page: how to set offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset

Im using jQuery on my page to jump / scroll to IDs.

This works from other pages with anchors like

```
<a href="other-page.php#jump-id">Jump & Scroll to ID on other page</a>
```

and on the same page only with anchors like

```
<a href="#jump-id">Jump / Scroll to ID on the same page</a>
```

Thats not the best solution because I have to change my nav menue but it works (I load another menue with other tags on the page).

Now im looking for a way to add an **offset of -230px** to the scroll / jump script, beause I have a **fixed header** on my page.

I think its simple but unfortunately im not a jQuery pro. How can I do this? Please Help me to add the -230 Offset to this function :)

The jQuery Code:

```
(function($){

    var jump=function(e)
    {
       if (e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr("href");
       }else{
           var target = location.hash;
       }

       $('html,body').animate(
       {
           scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
       },1000,function()
       {
           location.hash = target;
       });

    }

    $('html, body').hide()

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

        if (location.hash){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show()
                jump()
            }, 0);
        }else{
          $('html, body').show()
        }
    });

})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responsible for saying how much your page will scroll down is `scrollTop: $(target).offset().top`, so, if you want to offset `-230px` just subtract `230` from `$(target).offset().top`.

But, if you do this in your current code it will not work, because you are changing the hash using `location.hash = target;`. When you do this, your browser will locate the hash and jump to it (without animating, just jumping).

Observe this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pcyn2fvk/

If you click in the anchor, the page will scroll down to the content and after the scroll it will jump (this is caused by `location.hash = target;`).

Here is the demo without using `location.hash = target;`: http://jsfiddle.net/pcyn2fvk/1/

I assume you will need to change the hash, so, you can try a different approach, like this one explained by Lea Verou (http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/change-url-hash-without-page-jump/) that uses the History API instead of `location.hash`.

There are some other approaches, for example, you can remove the id of your target section (the one you clicked to scroll to) when you click to the anchor, then, when you change the location using `location.hash`, the browser will not find the clicked id, and will not jump to it, then, after that, you can reassign the id to your section.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I´ve read through the forums and found the same hints you posted. But unfortunately I´m stuck because I´m a bad programmer.

Comment: With what are you stuck? Have you seen the demos? I think you can try to use some of the things in demo to solve your problem! It's not hard!

Comment: this one worked! >>Here is the demo without using location.hash = target;: http://jsfiddle.net/pcyn2fvk/1/ Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach with anchor hashtags. This allows me to load a different page and scroll to my id with an offset.

In IE the scroll works well on all pages but all other browsers don't scroll on the smae page. If I click my link on the page wehre I want to scroll they jump to the hastags and dont use my jQuery scroll function. If I click the same link from an other URL the scroll works.

(other approach, only working from `<a href="page-b.php#anchor">Link on Page A to Page B</a>`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').hide();

    if (window.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top -230
                }, 1000)
        }, 0);
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').show();
    }
});
```